# Reloading Data in a UITableView when pressing a UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, objective-c-2.0

I have a UITabBarController as part of my app delegate and I want to trap when the user touches a specific tab (the favourites) and force the table within it to reload the data.

What would be best practice in this instance?

I have added the UITabBarDelegate protocol to my app delegate and implemented the didSelectViewController method.  So far so good.  Within the method I get a viewController, so I can check its title, etc. to determine which tab is selected.

How can I then send a reloadData message to the UITableView in the viewController?  I tried creating a method in my FavouritesViewController class and calling that but it does not work.

Example code:

```
#pragma mark UITabBarController delegate methods

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   // If the favourites tab is pressed then reload the data
   if (viewController.title = @"Favourites")
   {
      if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(reloadFavourites:)]) 
      {
         [viewController reloadFavourites];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add a `[UITableView reloadData]` to the tableViewController's `viewWillDisplay` method. This will cause the table to reload every time it is displayed.

If you want to force a reload will the tableview is already displayed, then calling reload from the method you created in the OP should work.

Comment: That is great thanks TechZen... Did as you said and put this in my viewController:

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
     [favouritesTableView reloadData];
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    }
and all works well, so no need to do what I was trying to do above.

Thanks again,

Dave

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code should refresh your table *every single time* the view appears.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```